# How can I split subdirs into smaller chunks for /bin/cat

Tags: bash, cat

I have the following situation. A directory with really a lot of subdirectories, and each of those subdirectories contains a file of interest that I want to concatenate.
e.g.,

```
my_dir/
    subdir1/
            subsubdir/
                file_of_interest1.txt
                ...
    subdir2/
            subsubdir/
                file_of_interest1.txt
                ...
    ...
```

Now, I tried using `cat my_dir/*/*/*.txt > all.txt`
But unfortunately, the subdirectory tree is so large that I get the following error:

```
bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

Is there a clever way to circumvent the problem, e.g., by concatenating the files in smaller chunks?
E.g., concatenating 1/3 of the subdirs, then another 1/3 and 1/3, and then joining them alltogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `find` go through the files and add as many as possible to each `cat` invocation's command line:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat '{}' + >all.txt
```

If your `find` doesn't support `-exec ... {} +` (which it should if compliant with current versions of the POSIX spec), there's also an approach using GNU extensions to make xargs safe:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 cat >all.txt
```

Using xargs without `-0` is unsafe -- it doesn't correctly handle filenames with newlines in that case, among other issues (some but not all of which can be avoided with other options). Think about a malicious user creating a file `$'foo \n/etc/passwd'` -- you don't want to run the risk of injecting `/etc/passwd` into your output.

Finally, there's the less-efficient, older way to use `find -exec` (which invokes a separate copy of `cat` for each file found):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat '{}' ';' >all.txt
```

...or, at a similar penalty (of invoking `cat` multiple times), you can simply use a loop in your shell script:

```
for f in my_dir/*/*/*.txt; do
  cat "$f"
done >all.txt
```

Note that this does the redirection on the entire loop, rather than (less efficiently) on a per-file basis.

---

Aside: If using POSIX sh or bash, quoting `{}` isn't necessary. However, you *do* need to quote `{}` if attempting to support `zsh`, and so I do so here.

Comment: Since GNU find already supports `-exec .. +`, using a GNU extension to work around the lack of it it will rarely be necessary. I'd suggest `-exec .. \;` as the alternative instead.

Comment: `-exec {} +` isn't a GNU extension, though, it's recent POSIX, so there are certainly non-GNU systems (such as modern BSD) which support it. `-exec {} ';'` is a fallback, to be sure, but it's one to be used only in cases of last resort.

Comment: I'm saying that `-print0` is a non-standard GNU extension, which primarily works on GNU find, which already supports `-exec .. +` in the first place.

Comment: @thatotherguy True. To be honest, I'm documenting the `xargs -0` approach to cut off other potential answers providing unsafe uses of xargs, not because it's likely to be actually useful.

Comment: Great, thanks, I went with the less efficient last option, all went fine! Now I have a plethora of alternatives to add to my reference snippets :)